# View: display nodes based on user selected preference

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm struggling with a view, principally the contextual filter.

As shown in the picture below (trying to make it clear):

My users can select in which products they are interested (through taxonomy, checkboxes). So they can receive information on the commercial offers when they log in.

My user B is a professional. He created a node for his company B (he's the author), and the company B is selling the products (selected also through taxonomy, checkboxes).
My user B create a commercial offer (= content type, node). This commercial offer is linked (through a field term reference) to his company B. In this way, there is a link between the commercial offer and the product.

The idea is to have a view which display only the commercial offer for the user interested in the product flower.

I created the view, displaying the commercial offer, but I cannot find the right contextual filters.

Thanks for your help.

[image]